# data from sql database not showing properly in php

Tags: php, sql, database

hi i got a sql database table which has some images and some description. i need to be able to display everything but is not working properly. i got 2 different pages. where all the database staff is and the index page. here is the function from the first page

```
function get_image() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table ';
    try {
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        $statement->closeCursor();
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        display_db_error($error_message);
    }
```

**Here is index.php:**

```
//on the index page i set up an array to display all the images but all i get is a 404  not  found. this is the index page  
<?php
require_once('model/database.php');
require_once('model/image_db.php');

// Set the array to display the images
$image_ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$images = array();
foreach ($image_ids as $image_id) {
$image = get_image();
$images[] = $image;   // add images to array
}

// Display the home page
 include('home_view.php');
?>
```

and on the home page i display everything but is not showing.. any ideas

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($images as $image) :
    // Get image data
    $imaget_price = $image['Price'];
    $description = $image['description'];


    // Get first paragraph of description
    $description = add_tags($description);
    $i = strpos($description, "</p>");
    $description = substr($description, 3, $i-3);
?>
 <tr>
        <td id="image_column">
            <img src="images/<?php echo $image['ID']; ?>.jpg"
                 alt="&nbsp;">
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
?>
```

Comment: Remove colon and add curly braces: `foreach ($images as $image) { .... }`

Comment: after i finish off the table i got a <?php endforeach; ?>.. so that isnt the problem

Comment: Read my answer.. you misspelt array();

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

You are binding values to a query that takes no values.

```
$statement->bindValue(1, $image_id);
```

You probably want something like this:

`$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE image_id = ?';`

Comment: it was misspelled in the question but not in the file.. also i got a <?php endforeach; ?> at the end of the table as well as a echo $image['ID'];.. so that aint it

Comment: Ok well. You should you add that code to your post or you're gonna keep getting downvoted and nobody will be able to help you. Read the rules on posting.

Comment: ok i edited it and added more or less the rest of the code.. i just left out some <tr> tags and some formatting

Comment: `function get_image($image_id) {` is never closed.

Comment: yes my mistake.. i fixed that.. so everything else should be ok right?

Comment: Did it fix your issue? If it still isn't printing out results you should echo out your `$result` variable and see if you get anything. It may be an issue with your query but it could also be an issue with sending the data from page to page.

Comment: thats what i thought it was. sending data from page to page. but i still cant figure it out. also the echo $result isnt returning anything either

Comment: i was doing some testing and if i give it a specific item it returns something instead of me saying where ID =? i said $query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = "image1"'; that returns the one image and everything else. but i need to return everything from the table not just anything that has "image1"

Comment: If you want to return everything from the table then you shouldn't be binding any parameters to your query.

Comment: so this guy right $statement->bindValue(1, $image_id); ?

Comment: Yes. Binding parameters is for putting where clauses into a prepared statement. Since you want to select everything from your table you don't want where statements, and in return, you don't want to bind values.

Comment: even if i dont bind the values it is still not returning all the values.. i edit the question without the binding can you take a look please